# ssh into fedora inside virtual box over internet

Tags: linux, ssh, virtualbox, fedora

I am running fedora server in a virtual box inside a windows 7 host. I can ssh into fedora from this windows 7 host.

How ever, I stay out of my place most of the times with a laptop at my disposal, but its config doesn't allow me to run vms on it.

What I am looking for is ssh-ing into my VM from my laptop over internet.

Is this possible ? if yes, how do I have to configure it ?

My virtual box is set up with 2 adapters i) NAT with port forwarding and ii) Host Only Adapter.

I am very new to linux and I need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem.

Basically the following needs to be done :

- Set the network adapter of vm in 'Bridged Mode'. [Do research on net about what it does]
- Set a static ip address to your fedora. [This can help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21432620/how-to-setup-static-ip-in-fedora-19)
- Now enable port-forwarding in your router and forward the SSH(port 22) to the VM's static ip.
- Install a ssh-server in your linux. [This can help!](http://www.tecmint.com/install-openssh-server-in-linux/)
- Download putty or any other client of your choice in the machine from which you want to access and   use your internet ip address as the host. You can use DNS services like no-ip etc if you have a dynamic ip address.

**You are ready to use your linux from any-where.**